# How to simplify $\int_0^T\int_0^T\mathbb{E}_{\pi}\left(\bar{f}(X_t)\bar{f}(X_s)\right)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, covariance, stochastic-approximation

I would like to get the result

$$\int_0^T\int_0^T\mathbb{E}_{\pi}\left(\bar{f}(X_t)\bar{f}(X_s)\right)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s = 2\int_0^T(T-s)\mathbb{E}_{\pi}\left(\bar{f}(X_s)\bar{f}(X_0)\right)\mathrm{d}s.$$

$X_t$ is a continuous time real-valued stochastic process, 
$$\bar{f}:=f - \mathbb{E}_{\pi}f,$$
and $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}$ is defined to be such that
$$\mathbb{E}_{\pi}f = \int_{\chi} f(x)\pi(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of $X_t$ and $\chi$ is the state space.

Comment: Your definition for $\bar{f}$ seems a random variable without any extra parameter. What does $\bar{f}(X_t)$ mean?

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that, I'd got that definition wrong. $\bar{f}$ is just $f$ recentered (so it has zero mean)

Comment: Aha, now it starts to make sense to me.

Comment: Are you actually asking about $$\int_0^T\int_0^T\mathbb{E}_{\pi}\left(\bar{f}(X_t)\bar{f}(X_s)\right)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm ds\ ?$$

Comment: @Did yes - I've edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Makes more sense now, but this is not quite the question you were asked yet: add to the pot that $\pi$ is not merely "some distribution" but **the stationary distribution** of $(X_t)$... And then the answer stems directly from the fact that, for every function $g$, $$E_\pi(g(X_t)g(X_s))$$ depends only on $$|t-s|$$

Comment: @Did got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Did in the comments, $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of $X_t$, and hence $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}\left(\bar{f}(X_t),\bar{f}(X_s)\right)=R_{\bar{f}}(t-s)$.

To evaluate the integral, let's start with the transformation $(t,s)\mapsto(t-s,t+s)$. Then, instead of integrating over the square $(0,0), (0,T), (T,0), (T,T)$, we're integrating over the square $(0,0), (-T,T), (T,T), (0,2T)$. Seeing as $f$ is real-valued, the autocorrelation function is even, and all we need to do is find the integral over the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (T,T), (0,2T)$ and multiply it by $2$.

Let's find the Jacobian of the transformation. Setting $(u,v)=(t-s,t+s)$ (and hence $t=\frac{u+v}{2}$, $s=\frac{u-v}{2}$), we get
$$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} &-\frac{1}{2}
\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Next, note that the cross-section with the line $x=s$ is $2(T-s)$. Putting all this together, our integral becomes
$$2\int_0^T 2(T-s)\left|-\frac{1}{2}\right|R_{\bar{f}}(s)\mathrm{d}s=2\int_0^T(T-S)\mathbb{E}_{\pi}\left(\bar{f}(X_s),\bar{f}(X_0)\right)\mathrm{d}s,$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi$ is the stationary distribution, then $\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_t)\bar{f}(X_s)]=\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_{|t-s|})\bar{f}(X_0)]$, and
\begin{align}\int_0^T&\int_0^T\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_t)\bar{f}(X_s)]\,dtds
=2\iint_{0\le s\le t\le T}\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_{|t-s|})\bar{f}(X_0)]\,dtds\\
&=2\iint_{0\le s\le s+\tau\le T}\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_{\tau})\bar{f}(X_0)]\,d\tau ds=2\iint_{0\le s\le T-\tau,0\le \tau\le T}\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_{\tau})\bar{f}(X_0)]\,dsd\tau\\
&=2\int_0^T(T-\tau)\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_{\tau})\bar{f}(X_0)]\,d\tau
=2\int_0^T(T-s)\mathsf{E}_{\pi}[\bar{f}(X_s)\bar{f}(X_0)]\,ds
\end{align}